# PHP: IDX api - Passing parameters in the query string

Tags: php, arrays, api, parameters

I'm working with the IDX api. I want to create pages by using the following query:

```
'queryString' => array(
  'idxID' => 'a01',
  'pt' => '1',
  'a_subdivisionName' => array('SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS')
)
```

The desired result is to create a page for the subdivision name 'SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS'.

on dumping the result, this is the output:

```
["queryString"]=>
string(73) "page=listings&idxID=a01&pt=1&a_subdivisionName%5B0%5D=SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS"
```

but what i expect is this:

```
["queryString"]=>
string(73) "page=listings&idxID=a015&pt=1&a_subdivisionName[]=SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS"
```

seems i'm not getting it right here:

```
'a_subdivisionName' =>array('SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS')
```

resulting in

```
a_subdivisionName%5B0%5D=SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS
```

instead of

```
a_subdivisionName[]=SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS
```

What am i missing?

**EDIT**

Here's how I'm building the url:

```
$data = array(
  'linkName' => 'SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS',
  'pageTitle' => 'SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS',
  'linkTitle' => 'SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS',
  'queryString' => array(
    'idxID' => 'a01',
    'pt' => '1',
    'a_subdivisionName' => array('SUN_CITY_LAS_VEGAS')
  )
);

$data = http_build_query($data);
```

Then i pass it to curl in a PUT request as follows:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: `%5B0%5D` is simply `[0]` in url-encoded form. whcih for PHP purposes are essentially identical.

Comment: ok. how do i get it to display the subdivision name as an array instead of url-encoding it as %5B0%5D?

Comment: what are you using to produce the url? because it's doing the technically correct thing. `[]` SHOULD be `%5B%5D` in a url.

Comment: I've edited my question. kindly see above

Comment: http_build_query is doing exactly what it should be doing. and you DON'T have to build a query manually anyways. curl will happily accept a php array and do all the encoding work itself.

Comment: You're right Marc. [ ] are indeed encoded to %5B%5D. nothing wrong there